# Display photographer's name in Business View via Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to read and display the photographer's name in Google Maps Business View using Google Maps Javascript API v3? I can't find any hint in the reference and I don't get the problem solved.
Thanks, Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You could use the @copyright param from the panorama.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaData

For example you could do this:

```js
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.416676, -64.1841580000002);
var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService (document.getElementById("map"));

streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(center, 30, function(panorama){console.log(panorama.copyright);});
```

This would create a new instance of streetViewService, then you ask for the panorama related to the "center" variable and finally, you could use the copyright variable.

Also, you could use just the description field from the location variable returned from the same getPanoramaByLocation call:

```js
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.416676, -64.1841580000002);
var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService (document.getElementById("map"));

streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(center, 30, function(panorama){console.log(panorama.location.description);});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that really looks interesting!
I will try that as soon as possible and report! 
(but it may take some time)